# Sudden unknown magento installations

Tags: magento

I just found out that someone has installed "MA2 Slideshow free"on my magento site. I have never heard of it before and it is not me who installed it.

I am not able to install the security patches right now because I do not have SSH access to my web host.

Do you think my site got hacked? How can I remove the installed "MA2 Slideshow free" from the admin panel?

Comment: Since this question is not directly coding related, but is related to how to deal with administrative issues on Magento, I suggest you ask on [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Seems to be a valid extension. Do you have a slideshow on your site? Is MA2 configured on the backend with the slides you see?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will take it on the Magento StackExchange from now on. Thanks!

Comment: This is a free widget from a company called MagenMarket. Did you buy a theme from them? Magento vendors sometimes bundle smaller widgets or extensions in with their themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install any custom Magento templates? These usually come packed with different extensions. When you install a template, you might even not notice, that additional modules get installed. You should start there.

Comment: I havent installed any new templates since the first time. And that was 9 months ago.